# Run-Time error '3075' Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hey everyone I keep getting the following error, Run-Time error '3075': syntax error in string in query expression "0,")'

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MobileDeviceUserList(sUser, sDevice, sMobileNumber, sIMEINumber, sSerialNumber, sAccessories, sNewSIMNumber, sComments, sRecorded) " & _
 "VALUES (" & Me.cboDevice & ",'" & Me.cboAccessories & ",'" & Me.txtUser & ",'" & Me.txtNumber & ",'" & Me.txtIMEI & ",'" & Me.txtSerial & ",'" & Me.txtNEWSIM & ",'" & Me.recRecorded & ",'" & _
 Me.txtComment & "')"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> until you reach the problematic string
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
3. Write exactly this on what you see:

---

```
?"INSERT INTO MobileDeviceUserList(sUser, sDevice, sMobileNumber, sIMEINumber, sSerialNumber, sAccessories, sNewSIMNumber, sComments, sRecorded) " & _
 "VALUES (" & Me.cboDevice & ",'" & Me.cboAccessories & ",'" & Me.txtUser & ",'" & Me.txtNumber & ",'" & Me.txtIMEI & ",'" & Me.txtSerial & ",'" & Me.txtNEWSIM & ",'" & Me.recRecorded & ",'" & _
 Me.txtComment & "')"
```

4. The "Debugging" should be quite easy now and the error must be evident.

Answer (score 0):

You are misplacing ticks (e.g. `'` ) in the string construction. Probably through copy and paste errors.

Example:

```
... & ",'" & Me.cboAccessories & ",'" & Me.txtUser & ",'" & Me.txtNumber & ",'" & ...
```

... should be something closer to,

```
... & ",'" & Me.cboAccessories & '",'" & Me.txtUser & '"," & Me.txtNumber & ",'" & ...
```

I cannot supply a foolproff answer as I do not know what fields are text, numeric, dates or memos. Maybe do a string construction into a string var and debug.print the var to see the result.